# Reduxjs, Reactjs: Delete item, give undo feature

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux, redux-thunk

I am working on a application using Reactjs and Redux. I have a requirement, where I need to delete the item from list. Here the delete function works all good, but I need to give user an option to undo delete. 
My current method is

```
return dispatch => {
        dispatch(deletePosts(postID));

        return fetch(API.url(postID), {
            method: API.type,
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        }).then(function(response) {
           if(!response.ok) {
            //revert back
           }
        });
    }
```

Here I first delete the post from the state and then call fetch request to delete from server. But if I give any such feature to reverse, I can't just delete from server. I think it's reasonable to display undo option for probably 3 secs and perform the action. 
Can you please help me how I can achieve this and if any other web application has implemented this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Keep a reference to the initial state of the list, then create a copy with an item removed, then if necessary, revert back to the initial state.

```
const postsBefore = getPosts();

deletePosts(postID);

return fetch(API.url(postID), {
  method: API.type,
  credentials: 'same-origin'
}).then(function(response) {
  if(!response.ok) {
    revertPosts(postsBefore);
  }
});
```

It's important that your reducers don't perform mutations, otherwise your delete function would modify the original data structure, which would also change your `postsBefore` reference. When you tried to revert to `postsBefore`, you'd be reverting to the exact same data.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the response. I guess my  question wasn't very explanatory. The problem is I want to implement "Undo" feature. So if I delete the content from server "Database", I won't have anything to revert back to. So I am having difficulty to architect the "Undo" feature in asynchronous environment. Hope this explains better

Comment: So long as you get a reference to the data before you make the call to the server, it doesn't matter. Even if the value is deleted from the store and the database, you still have a reference to the original value, which you can inject back into both.

Comment: You are right but the problem is, there is no revert back on server, if you delete from database its final. So I want to control everything on client side and send final API call.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. First, to implement this logic on the client side:

1. When user clicks "delete" button you should mark post in your state
   as `toBeDeleted` but don't send real delete request to the server.
2. Delay calling of your `deletePostForReal` action using `setTimeout` for 3 seconds.
3. Your list component should show "cancel" button instead of post if
   it is marked as `toBeDeleted`.
4. If user user clicks "Cancel" – remove `toBeDeleted` field from the post.
5. In your delayed `deletePostForReal` action check if post has `toBeDeleted` field. If yes, send real request to the server and remove post from the store. If no – don't do anything.

Second option is to do it on the server side. In that case your server should implement similar logic itself and provide different endpoints for the client side. For example `post/ID/delete` and `post/ID/undo_delete`.

Comment: Hi @trashgenerator, thanks. It's similar to what I am trying to do. But I am not sure how can I call the cancel option. Can you please check this https://gist.github.com/Vivekbhusal/a62bc0dc88daf4c1008c

Comment: Seems you didn't post your reducers. Can you please make jsfiddle?